# SQL Statement Doesn't make sense

Tags: sql, json, node.js

So I'm using a node module called json-sql
https://github.com/2do2go/json-sql

but the end result is

```
    sql.query
// insert into users (name, lastname, age, gender) values ($p1, $p2, 24, $p3);

sql.values
// { p1: 'John', p2: 'Snow', p3: 'male' }
```

Is there a quick way to make that SQL readable? I would like to have a bunch of these statements and make that into a .sql file to be run on a sql server later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the library is unable to natively produce exectuable MS SQL-compliant statements.

A valid MS SQL prepared statement would look like this:

```
sp_EXECUTEsql @statement=N'Select @p as t', @parameters = N'@p varchar(50)', @p=N'Test'
```

So in this case you'd want to do three things:

1. Use the library's `options` parameter to set the ValuesPrefix to `@` rather than the default `$`
2. Write some sort of method to take the `sql.values` result and generate both the value for `@parameters` above as well as each individual parameter value.
3. Concatenate all the pieces together into a statement resembling the one above.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can use option `separatedValues: false` to get plain sql-query without placeholders.

For example, in your case:

```
var jsonSql = require('json-sql')({separatedValues: false});

sql.query
// insert into "users" ("name", "lastname", "age", "gender") values (\'John\', \'Snow\', 24, \'male\');
```

Then you just have to replace the characters you don't want (double quotes for example);

I hope that somebody find this useful.

Answer (score -1):

The module apparently intends you to insert the values described by the associative array `sql.values` into the query string given by `sql.query`.  The result for those particular `sql.query` and `sql.values` would be

```
insert into users (name, lastname, age, gender) values ('John', 'Snow', 24, 'male')
```

This is similar in appearance to, but different in implementation from the concept of a "prepared statement" present in many programmatic database interfaces.

Comment: Note that SQL requires the hyphens around string literals, as shown, so this is not a straight string interpolation.

Comment: That's not how the module works, you pass it a MongoDB query object and it returns sql.query and sql.values, which you have to then construct into your own database call. So you would pass SQL.query and SQL.values over the wire to some service and it would prepare them, execute them, and return the data.

Comment: @KyleHale Thanks for clarifying.  However the module works, though, the question was what query was represented by the provided data.  I presented that query, and described how one gets there from the data.  Nevertheless, I have updated my answer to clarify that it is the user, not the module, who is intended to construct the query from the data.